# How to minimise number of routes in my Flask webapp

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to minimize the number of routes and database tables in my simple clothing ecommerce site. My site has four product categories: Coat, Shirt, Trouser, Shoe.

Each category currently has its own table in the database:

```
class Coat(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
price = db.Column(db.Float)
image1 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True, default='default.jpg')
image2 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
```

**I would like to combine all products into a single database with 'Category' being a column inside this Product database.**

Each category also currently has its own route and template:

```
@app.route('/coats')
def coats():
products = Coat.query.all()
return render_template('coats.html', products=products, title='Coats')
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="product">
            <a href="{{ url_for('product_coat', id=product.id) }}">
            <img src="static/images/coats/{{ product.image1 }}" class="image"></a>
            <p class="name">{{ product.name }}</p>
            <p class="price">{{ product.price }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

When a products link is followed, a product page is displayed, again using individual routes for each category:

```
@app.route('/product_coat/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def product_coat(id):
product = Coat.query.get(id)
return render_template('product_coat.html', title='Product', 
    product=product)
```

Currently my navbar in "base.html" looks like this:

```html
<nav>
    <a href="{{ url_for('coats') }}"><h3>Coats</h3></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('shirts') }}"><h3>Shirts</h3></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('trousers') }}"><h3>Trousers</h3></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('shoes') }}"><h3>Shoes</h3></a>
</nav>
```

I realise this is a rather large post so to summarise,

**If I were to combine all four database tables into one product table with a new 'category' column, how would I**:

1. Create navbar links for these categories?
2. Create a route that handles displaying only products from the selected category?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking, mainly because the Title of the Question and the question at the bottom 1 and 2 are quite different, and misleading. To what I understand, you want to be able to handle 'categories' in like a tag?  Similar like in Stackoverflow, you can search by tag and so it sorts all element by desidered Tag?  Also have categories in a separate Navbar?

Comment: Personally, I think the question content is pretty clear. As such, I've provided a detailed answer below. Its a good point you raise @federico about the title, it seems more of a side-affect of restructuring the app rather than the core goal. But, overall, I'm not sure why the question was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't down vote too

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query parameters to a new route,

```
@app.route('/product/', methods=['GET'])
def product_list(id):
  item = request.args.get('item')
  product = products.all.filter(type=item)
  return render_template(f"{item}.html", title=item,product=product)
```

then when you load the page, you can call `url/?item=coat` and it will filter the data.

*that product filter line might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is attempt to follow a more [RESTful design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

The main idea is to add a parameter to your routes to represent the `category`. This would be similar to what you've done for the product ID. Importantly, you would have only **one** HTML template for the *products* page (the page that lists all the products of a particular category) and **one** HTML template for the *product* page (the page for listing the details of one product of a particular category).

So your two existing routes could become something like this:

(Note your logic should ensure an invalid product category and/or ID is correctly handled)

```
@app.route('/products/<product_category>/<product_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def product(product_category, product_id):
    product = <your database logic utilizing the product_category and product_id + error handling>
    return render_template('product.html', product=product, title=product.name)

@app.route('/products/<product_category>', methods=['GET'])
def products(product_category):
    products = <your database logic utilizing the product_category + error handling>
    return render_template('products.html', products=products, title=product_category.title())
```

Your navbar HTML could end up looking like this:

(Here we specify the 2nd route and supply just the category)

```
  <nav>
    <a href="{{ url_for('products', product_category='coats') }}"><h3>Coats</h3></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('products', product_category='shirts') }}"><h3>Shirts</h3></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('products', product_category='trousers') }}"><h3>Trousers</h3></a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('products', product_category='shoes') }}"><h3>Shoes</h3></a>
  </nav>
```

Finally, your product display HTML could end up like this:

(Here we specify the 1st route and supply the category and product ID -- since we're linking to a specific product in this case)

```
<div class="product">
  <a href="{{ url_for('product', product_category=product.category, product_id=product.id) }}">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/coats/' + product.image1) }} class="image"></a>
  <p class="name">{{ product.name }}</p>
  <p class="price">{{ product.price }}</p>
</div>
```

Also, I suggest investigating the [MVC design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which is highly prevalent in Flask applications.